# MySQL LEFT JOIN 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables:

```
Persons (PersonID, Name, SS)
Fears (FearID, Fear)
Person_Fear (ID, PersonID, FearID)
```

Now I'd like to list every person with whatever fear is linked to them (can be multiple fears but can also be none). The persons table has to be shown even if a person doesn't have a fear linked to them.

I think I need to do a LEFT JOIN, but my code doesn't seem to work:

```
SELECT persons.name, 
       persons.ss, 
       fears.fear 
FROM   persons 
       LEFT JOIN fears 
              ON person_fear.personid = person_fear.fearid
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 94):

You are trying to join `Person_Fear.PersonID` onto `Person_Fear.FearID` - This doesn't really make sense. You probably want something like:

```
SELECT Persons.Name, Persons.SS, Fears.Fear FROM Persons
LEFT JOIN Person_Fear
    INNER JOIN Fears
    ON Person_Fear.FearID = Fears.FearID
ON Person_Fear.PersonID = Persons.PersonID
```

This joins `Persons` onto `Fears` via the intermediate table `Person_Fear`. Because the join between `Persons` and `Person_Fear` is a `LEFT JOIN`, you will get all `Persons` records.

Alternatively:

```
SELECT Persons.Name, Persons.SS, Fears.Fear FROM Persons
LEFT JOIN Person_Fear ON Person_Fear.PersonID = Persons.PersonID
LEFT JOIN Fears ON Person_Fear.FearID = Fears.FearID
```

Comment: I downvoted because you're original post didn't reference all 3 tables. You have corrected that, but you have the nesting of the On clauses wrong.

Comment: +1 - I know, this looks like the only correct answer so far (after any edits at least).

Comment: @Aheho True - his table definitions weren't in code blocks originally so I missed them. I've corrected the nesting but this makes my answer pretty much identical to yours, so I'll offer an alternative too.

Comment: Incidentally, I'm not sure which of these would be more efficient. I would wager the latter as it eliminates the need to join rows of `Person_Fear` onto `Fears` if there's no `Person` to `Person_Fear` relationship. Can anyone provide insight?

Comment: Your alternative solution seems to work perfectly, thanks! EDIT: The other one as well now I see. Thanks for showing me both solutions.

Comment: @AntP In my opinion, you're delving into the category of premature optimization when you start asking questions like that. Get your indices in order, and don't sweat detail like that. A decent query optimizer will probably generate a very similar query plan for each.

Comment: Regarding the alternative query with 2 left joins:
If you have an entry in Person_Fear with a FearID that doesn't exist in the Fears table, you'll end up with a NULL entry in the FEAR column in final result. If a person has multiple Person_fear entries with invalid FearIDs you'll have multiple rows with NULL Fear. So the queries are not equivalent.

Comment: @Aheho: Actually, no. @AntP is correct, it's a pretty good question. And many optimizers would produce different query plans. One reason being that the queries are not logically identical. (OK, they are but only if there is an FK from `Person_Fear` towards `Fear`). And MYSQL's primitive optimizer may not be aware and use that info.

Answer (score 31):

try this

```
    SELECT p.Name, p.SS, f.Fear 
    FROM Persons p 
    LEFT JOIN Person_Fear fp 
    ON p.PersonID = fp.PersonID
    LEFT JOIN Fear f
    ON f.FearID = fp.FearID
```

Answer (score 21):

Try this definitely work.

```
SELECT p.PersonID AS person_id,
   p.Name, p.SS, 
   f.FearID AS fear_id,
   f.Fear 
   FROM person_fear AS pf 
      LEFT JOIN persons AS p ON pf.PersonID = p.PersonID 
      LEFT JOIN fears AS f ON pf.PersonID = f.FearID 
   WHERE f.FearID = pf.FearID AND p.PersonID = pf.PersonID
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, but i solved it by removing the `AS` variables and just using full table names

Comment: Can anyone comment on the performance difference between the Left, Left joins vs Left,Inner joins

Comment: @anveshtummala -- Performance:  No diff.  "INNER" is ignored.  But, the table is probably poorly indexed; see [_Many-to-many_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)

Answer (score 13):

```
Select Persons.Name, Persons.SS, Fears.Fear
From Persons
LEFT JOIN Persons_Fear
ON Persons.PersonID = Person_Fear.PersonID
LEFT JOIN Fears
ON Person_Fear.FearID = Fears.FearID;
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please describe what this code does that the OP was not achieving.

Comment: this is quite practical answer. you guys should stop discouraging newbies. add some comments yourself if you find it too code-y

Answer (score 11):

```
Select 
    p.Name,
    p.SS,
    f.fear
From
    Persons p
left join
        Person_Fear pf
    inner join
        Fears f
    on
        pf.fearID = f.fearID
 on
    p.personID = pf.PersonID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.*, f.Fear
FROM Persons p
LEFT JOIN Person_Fear pf ON pf.PersonID = p.PersonID
LEFT JOIN Fears f ON f.FearID = pf.FearID
ORDER BY p.PersonID
```

---

1. You need to select from the `Persons` table to ensure you generate a row for every person, whether they have fears or not.
2. Then you can left join `Person_Fear` to every person, which will just be `NULL` if they don't have any entries (as you want).
3. Finally, you left join `Fears` on `Person_Fear` so that you can select the name of the fear.
4. Optionally, add an order so that each person has all their fears listed together, even if they were added to the `Person_Fear` table at different times.