# Get Data From A Database

Tags: sql, database

Edit* I want to get the actual info. Right now I would get something like this:
Bob
21
1

I want to replace 21 with California and 1 with United States

If I have a database such as:

**Client** 
Name
StateId
CountryId

Then what is the best way to get that data? Currently I have:

```
SELECT * FROM Client

SELECT * FROM Client
LEFT JOIN StateId, 
ON Client.StateId=State.Id

SELECT * FROM Client
LEFT JOIN CountryId, 
ON Client.CountryId=Country.Id
```

But this gives me 3 tables. Is this how database information should be read or should I get back one table that with the information in it?

Comment: What are you trying to acheive? If you just want the raw data, your first query will work fine.

Comment: What do you want to retrieve with your query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do multiple joins in the same query. Something like:

```
SELECT Client.Name, State.Name, Country.Name
FROM Client
LEFT JOIN State ON Client.StateId=State.Id
LEFT JOIN Country ON Client.CountryId=Country.Id
```

This assume that your states in `State` table and countries are in `Country` table.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't realize you could do that! I also found this explains more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222097/mysql-left-join-3-tables

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Client

SELECT * FROM Client
LEFT JOIN StateId, 
ON Client.StateId=State.Id

SELECT * FROM Client
LEFT JOIN CountryId, 
ON Client.CountryId=Country.Id
```

You can turn this into 1 query with the following

```
SELECT c.ClientID, c.Name, s.Name, co.Name from Client c 
inner join Country co on c.Countryid = co.ID 
left join state s on c.StateID = s.ID
```

I believe you will want an inner join actually, but this is my interpretation. Left joins will return all values in table a regardless of a value being present in table b, so if you want all people regardless of whether they have a country ID then yes a left join, but if you want all people with a country relationship and a state relationship I believe you will initially want an inner join. the second join may be inner as well, depending on if nulls are acceptable in your end table result.

Also, left joins can return some unwanted results, if a person is in multiple countries or has multiple states you could return more rows than necessary. You should establish the business rules of each table before implementing the contents of two left joins into your result set.

This may be for a class, and has no real purpose for business, but it is best not to assume and give you all possible scenarios of your result set.

What I'm doing is returning all the clients with a corresponding countryID, i don't want to return nulls here because in your next join relationship you will also return a null if country is the link between client and state.