# How to join this 5 tables in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

I have 5 tables that I need to connect to get the necessary data.

**Table1**

```
id | number
1  | 1
2  | 5
```

**Table 2**

```
id | number | user_id
1  | 1      | 9
2  | 5      | 8
```

**Table 3**

```
id | name | 
8  | john | 
9  | jane |
```

**Table 4**

```
id | email
6  | johndoe@example.com
```

**Table 5**

```
id | table4_id | table3_id
1  | 6         | 8
```

Table 1 is my main table and I want to add the name and email from table 3 and 4 respectively to my select query of table 1, but in order to do so, I would need to use table 2 and 5 to connect them as there is no direct relationship between table 1 and table 3 and 4. I only know how to join 3 tables and not 5 tables and it seems confusing to me on how to proceed with this.

I followed the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25580544/6444625) to join Table 1,2 and 3. But I don't know how to proceed with table 4 and 5.

This is the query I tried:

```
SELECT table1.number, table2.number, table2.user_id, table3.id, table3.name,
table4.id, table4.email, table5.table4_id, table3_id
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
    INNER JOIN table3
        //this query will work if I don't include this 2 inner joins
         INNER JOIN table4
            INNER JOIN table5
            ON table3.id = table5.table3_id
         ON table5.table4_id = table4.id
       //
      ON table2.user_id= table3.id
ON table2.number = table1.number;
```

**ERROR: (if included the inner join for table 4 and 5)**

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'ON table2.user_id= table3.id

Comment: Add the query you have tried

Comment: Usually One by one

Comment: @Jens added the query I tried

Comment: @RiggsFolly added the query

Comment: The syntax is `JOIN tablename ON someid=someid` put your ON clauses with the relevant JOIN then you are probably done

Comment: @RiggsFolly the ON clauses are there together with their JOIN statements

Comment: Not they are NOT Put them together. The ON tells the preceeding JOIN what links to use. See @Jens answer

Comment: @RiggsFolly oh so that's what you meant by that, That's how I did it in my code. Sorry about that

Comment: @RiggsFolly You sure are a bully, just because you have that many points don't give you the authority to talk like that, and besides that the posted query is exactly what I have in my code and that I did not know of the proper convention of placing the ON after the JOIN as I just followed the example in the link provided. So if you don't have anything good to say then please shut up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right Syntax is `select .. from .. join .. on .. join ..on ....`

```
SELECT table1.number, table2.number, table2.user_id, table3.id, table3.name,  table4.id, table4.email, table5.table4_id, table3_id
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.number = table1.number
INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.user_id= table3.id
INNER JOIN table5 ON table3.id = table5.table3_id
INNER JOIN table4 ON table5.table4_id = table4.id
```

Comment: Should the semicolon be at the left join statement?

Comment: @hungrykoala sorry copy/paste Problem. Have changed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below structure. I made it from the structure you given in question

```
select t1.number, t2.number, t2.user_id, t3.id, t3.name,t4.id, t4.email, t5.t4_id, t3_id 
from table5 as t5 
join table4 as t4 on t5.table4_id = t4.id 
join table3 as t3 on t5.table3_id=t3.id 
join table2 as t2 on t2.user_id = t3.id 
join table1 as t1 on t2.number=t1.number
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Below code. Hope this will work.

```
Select t3.name,t4.email,t1.number,t2.user_id 
from table3 t3 JOIN table5 t5 ON t3.id=t5.table3_id 
JOIN table4 t4 ON t4.id=t5.table4_id
JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.user_id=t3.id
JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.number=t2.number;
```