# MySQL select if all values belonging to id are present in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

Basically I have two tables:

```
rid|element     id|element  
 1 |   x        1 | a    
 1 |   y        2 | b    
 1 |   z        3 | c
 1 |   a        4 | d
 2 |   b        5 | e
 2 |   c        6 | x
 2 |   d        7 | z
 3 |   e        
 3 |   z  
 3 |   x
```

and I want to return `rid = 2, 3` but not `1` because the element `y` is not present in the second table. I think the answer lies in the type of join I use but I haven't really been able to wrap my head around those

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL LEFT JOIN 3 tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222097/mysql-left-join-3-tables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with left joining the first table to the second and then aggregating by `rid` to check that every `element` from the first table in fact matched to an `element` in the second table.

```
SELECT t1.rid
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.element = t2.element
GROUP BY t1.rid
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN t2.element IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```