# MySql JOIN syntax with multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join, syntax

Can someone explain why in the first solution for [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16222147/12842060) the LEFT JOIN can be nested between the INNER JOIN table name and ON clause?

```
SELECT Persons.Name, Persons.SS, Fears.Fear FROM Persons
LEFT JOIN Person_Fear
    INNER JOIN Fears
    ON Person_Fear.FearID = Fears.FearID
ON Person_Fear.PersonID = Persons.PersonID
```

I can't find anything describing this syntax and I'm not sure what the point is. The answer has 2 solutions, and I would've naturally done the second solution having never seen the first solution's syntax before.

Is there performance benefits for either?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that answer is simply wrong.

Comment: Although I just tried it and didn't get a syntax error.

Comment: For the performance: I would say that the performance would not differ. The query optimization code will check for the potentially best solution anyway in which order of statements can be changed. However: Run an explain for both solutions and check if the plan is different.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen thanks for the performance advice, we will definitely check that out.

Comment: What if a person has no fear?

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters to the `FROM` keyword are what the MySQL documentation calls *table_references*, and its syntax is described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html). There's lots of recursive references in the syntax, and I think this is what allows that syntax. I've copied what I think are relevant excerpts from the BNF.

```
table_references:
    escaped_table_reference [, escaped_table_reference] ...

escaped_table_reference: {
    table_reference
  | { OJ table_reference }
}

table_reference: {
    table_factor
  | joined_table
}

joined_table: {
    table_reference {[INNER | CROSS] JOIN | STRAIGHT_JOIN} table_factor [join_specification]
  | table_reference {LEFT|RIGHT} [OUTER] JOIN table_reference join_specification
  | table_reference NATURAL [INNER | {LEFT|RIGHT} [OUTER]] JOIN table_factor
}
```

The nested

```
    Person_Fear
    INNER JOIN Fears
    ON Person_Fear.FearID = Fears.FearID
```

is a *joined_table*, which can be used as the *table_reference* in the first `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. I did come across that page, but sometimes I'm not sure what I'm looking at on there. Your explanation definitely helped.

Comment: Don't feel bad, it's hard to understand with all the recursive references. It took me several readings before I decided it allowed this.

Answer (score 0):

I would add parens to make it clear:

```
SELECT  Persons.Name, Persons.SS, Fears.Fear
    FROM  Persons
    LEFT JOIN  ( Person_Fear
                  INNER JOIN  Fears
                        ON Person_Fear.FearID = Fears.FearID
               )
        ON Person_Fear.PersonID = Persons.PersonID
```

or

```
SELECT  Persons.Name, Persons.SS, Fears.Fear
    FROM  ( Persons
               LEFT JOIN  Person_Fear
                  ON Person_Fear.PersonID = Persons.PersonID
          )
    INNER JOIN  Fears  ON Person_Fear.FearID = Fears.FearID
```

depending which you wanted.

Then I would get `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to see if it parsed it "correctly".